# sending simple int from UWP app to another program

Tags: c++, sockets, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm lost at a seemlingly minor problem. I have a UWP app from windows samples, which counts the faces detected by the camera. I want that app to send that number to another program. I've tried doing it by clipboard, however as the other program is constantly checking the clipboard it wouldn't work.
Then I thought of a simple socket connection but I can't seem to get it working in UWP as all infos seem to be in C# not C++. 
Can someone gimme a hint how to send a single int over a tcp socket to another client?
Or any other suggestions how to achieve that?
I'm really desperate...

thanks in advance.

Comment: Your post  in its current form is too broad and not a good fit for Stack Overflow. Please visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and read the section [how do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1):

In UWP, [app services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-services) are the standard way of communicating between apps. You need to [create an app service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service) in the source app then consume the service in the second one. The app service also can be consumed by [non-UWP apps](https://github.com/arunjeetsingh/SampleCode/tree/master/Win32AppServiceClient/Win32AppServiceClient).